# Serial Port WriteFile() fails with E_INVALIDARG

Tags: visual-studio, serial-port

I am trying to write a program to communicate to my device through USB connected to COM7, but I am having problems writing to it.

Here is how I open the handle

```
hPort = CreateFile(
    "COM7",         // address of name of the communications device
    GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, // access (read-write) mode
    0,                  // share mode
    NULL,                   // address of security descriptor
    OPEN_EXISTING,      // how to create
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, // file attributes
    NULL                    // handle of file with attributes to copy
);

//Get COM Settings
dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
//Baud Rate COMBO_BAUD
i = SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, COMBO_BAUD, LB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
dcb.BaudRate = 9600; //BaudInt[i];
//Byte Size COMBO_BITS
i = SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, COMBO_BITS, LB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
dcb.ByteSize = 8; //BitsInt[i];
//Parity COMBO_PARITY
i = SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, COMBO_PARITY, LB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY; //ParityInt[i];
//Stop Bits COMBO_STOP
i = SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, COMBO_STOP, LB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //StopInt[i];

if (!::SetCommState (hPort,&dcb))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to Set COM settings", "Status", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return;
}

COMMTIMEOUTS comTimeOut;                
comTimeOut.ReadIntervalTimeout = 3000;
comTimeOut.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 3000;
comTimeOut.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 2000;
comTimeOut.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 3000;
comTimeOut.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 2000;
SetCommTimeouts(hPort,&comTimeOut);
```

And how I write to the handle

```
BOOL success = WriteFile(hPort, "meas:volt?\n", sizeof("meas:volt?\n"), &dwRet, NULL);
DWORD error = GetLastError();
HRESULT result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(error);
```

I keep getting "E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid" as the error.
Can anyone help me figure this problem out? I am using usbser.sys (serial port driver)

Comment: If you use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in `CreateFile`, you need to provide `OVERLAPPED` pointer in `WriteFile`

Comment: Calling GetLastError() *without* checking if the function actually failed is a bug.  You must check the *success* variable value, rock-hard requirement, failure to do so produces a random error code.

Comment: Ohh ok thank you Alex! I didnt realize I needed the overlapped pointer. I was able to add it in and everything communicates correctly now! 

Thanks for the tip